# To add reference in latex Overleaf

Tags: cross-referencing

can someone help me what is the problem in the picture? I want to add a reference in latex overleaf. I saved the reference in a new file (reference.bib) but after compiling, it doesn't show any reference.

[image]

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_bibliographies_on_Overleaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have not cited anything in the document body. If you want to list all the items in the `bib` file, `\nocite{*}` would be helpful.